# SSRS subscription only when data in report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have setup a report that uses a stored procedure to create the dataset. I am sending this report to 4 users using an email subscription on a daily basis. More often than not, the report will not have any data. How do I get the subscription to only send the email when the report has data?

Answer (score 4):

Anyone else who stumbles across this, you can try this little trick.  It will throw an error, which will prevent the report from being sent.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('No Results', 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a data-driven report, if you're on Enterprise edition. If not, you'll need to see if any rows were returned from the SP first, and only execute the subscription if there are. This is pseudo-SQL, in the absence of a lot of context, however, something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YouTable JOIN YourOtherTable WHERE ...) BEGIN
    EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='a6c151ca-ff47-46c0-b807-ad1ac8116769';
END
```